# How do I execute a stored procedure that takes a parameter in Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a stored procedure that takes parameters and I would like to run it from a CodeFirst implementation of EF 6.1.3. This particular sp deletes rows from a table and doesn't return anything except the number of rows deleted. I'm not quite sure how to do it. Let's say the stored procedure is sp_DeleteTheseRows and it takes a single parameter, @TheParam. How would that look? I guess it would use ExecuteSQLCommand. Would it be:

MyContext.Database.ExecuteSQLCommand("exec dbo.sp_DeleteTheseRows @TheParam", new SqlParameter("@TheParam", userSuppliedParam));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I discovered. All the following are solutions to the question above:

DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec dbo.sp_DeleteTheseRows @p0", MyValue);

Turns out you don't really need the EXEC

DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.sp_DeleteTheseRows @p0", MyValue);

DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.sp_DeleteTheseRows @Code",new SqlParameter("@Code", MyValue));

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined the type of command as storedprocedure like,
    cmd.CommandType = StoredProcedure;